# NET 6 WEB API ENABLE CERTIFICATE HTTPS ON AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ec2

I have a problem, I can't generate the certificates in AWS EC2

Linux AWS

I trying execute this command in SSH - `docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=https://+:3001 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development" -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:3001 $MY ECR CONTAINER HERE$`

i try too `docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=https://+:3001 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development" -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:3001 -v ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=$MY PW$* -v ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=%USERPROFILE%/aspnet/https/aspnetapp.pfx $MY CONTAINER$`

[Error on SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G88En.png)

[My Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMv9C.png)

[My Launch Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLfoq.png)

[DOTNET INFO ON LINUX AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imrur.png)

[AWS CERTIFICATE MANAGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16m94.png)

it works perfectly on HTTP 80 but to unable HTTPS 443, a docker need a certificate.

what do i need to do to generate this certificate in aws linux?

Edit*
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[6                                                                                                             0]
Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may n                                                                                                             ot be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable whe                                                                                                             n container is destroyed.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
No XML encryptor configured. Key {f37427eb-3dc8-4d33-9177-92caadc2c880} ma                                                                                                             y be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

Comment: ** OBS: I TRY COMMAND dotnet dev-certs https --trust and response is "Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. Trusting the certificate on Linux distributions automatically is not supported. For instructions on how to manually trust the certificate on your Linux distribution, go to https://aka.ms/dev-certs-trust
"

Comment: This is for development time or something else?

Comment: I'm testing the deploy in dev for now but I intend to put it in a production environment, could that be why?

Comment: Are you planning to run this way in production? The dev cert is for development purposes only. When you run in production its expected that you would have a real certificate from a trusted CA.

Comment: in AWS CERTIFICATE MANAGER I have a valid certificate, however, I don't know how to make it work with aspnet in EC2

Comment: What assets do you have from the AWS certificate manager?

Comment: I put it above, image 5

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS, by assets I was asking about the files  (usually the certificate and the private key) used to configure the server for https.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching find the following answers and my project is on LIVE.

1º I edited my program.cs so that it uses HTTPS Redirection and HSTS and configured the Forward Headers
Follow the codes.
`builder.Services.Configure(options =>
{
options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;

});`

```
app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
        "Api Documentation for MyLandingApp");
    });
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("MyLandingAppPolicy");
app.UseForwardedHeaders();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.IsHttps || context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
    {
        await next();
    }
    else
    {
        string queryString = context.Request.QueryString.HasValue ? context.Request.QueryString.Value : string.Empty;
        var https = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path + queryString;
        context.Response.Redirect(https);
    }
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

2º I added some stuff in my Appsettings.Json

```
  "https_port": 3001,
```

3ºI changed my DockerFile to create a self certificate and enable HTTPS on docker run
.
[Docker File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiWpY.png)

4ª I changed the docker container execution string, removed the HTTP port that I wouldn't use anyway, I'll explain later.

```
docker run --rm -p 3001:3001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=https://+:3001 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Production" -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:3001 $MY CONTAINER IN ESR$
```

5º I configured the loudbalancer like this:

HTTP80 - [Loud Balancer http80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUqEX.png)
HTTPS443 - [Loud bALANCER https443](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gELGv.png)
Só que tem o macete...

you need to create the target group pointing to the main server, then you will take the private IP and create a new target group

[Target Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4U7G.png)

With this you will have done the redirection and CERTIFICATE configuration for your API.

Remembering that in Listener https 443 you need a valid certificate.